# Select all from DB where the content has defined

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to retrieve a list of database records which have specific 'interest codes' inside of the 'custom_fields' table. So for example right now there is 100 records, I need the Name, Email and Interest Code from each of those records.

I've tried with the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE list = '27' AND custom_fields LIKE 'CV'
```

But with no luck, the response was:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0003 sec )
```

You can see in this screenshot that at-least two rows have 'CV' inside custom_fields. Whilst within the database it's not called 'Interest Code', that's what they are so therefore why I am referencing it in this way.

[image]

Comment: use '%CV%' to get lines with characters before and/or after 'CV'

Comment: I suppose list is an integer. So you can skip the quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose your "search string" inside some wildcards:

```
select * from subscribers where list=27 and custom_fields like '%CV%';
```

The `%` wildcard means "zero or more chacarcters at this position". The "_" wildcard means "a character in this position". Please read [the reference manual on the topic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html). Also, you may want to read about [regular expressions in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html) for more complex string comparissons.

Comment: Or perhaps `LIKE '%\%CV\%%'`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams That's up to the OP author... if he also needs to match specifically the `%` character, then of course escaping it with ` \ ` as you say *will* be needed.

Comment: And I did need to specifically target, just did a test and I found all results with CV interest code at first, but a few which had RCV, those were not needed so I updated this with the escaping method and was able to stop selecting those with 'RCV' and not just 'CV'. Fantastic, thank you.

Comment: @JordanC26 Happy to help. As I mentioned in my answer, I recommend you take a look on how to use regular expressions to match more complex patterns (just in case you need it).